# В чем разница между единицами измерения px, dp, dip и sp на Андроиде?

Tags: android

В чем отличие этих единиц измерения на Андроиде?

- `px`
- `dip`
- `dp`
- `sp`

Comment: Данный вопрос и ответ на него я взял с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android), комментарии и правки приветствуются :)

Comment: На начальном этапе юзай dp для всего, кроме текста. Для текста используй sp. Это единственное что бы я добавил к ответу ниже.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension):

1. > **px**
   > > Пиксель — соответствует одному пикселю на экране. Не рекомендуется использовать, так как на разных устройствах элементы будут выглядеть по-разному (физический размер одного пикселя на каждом устройстве разный).
2. > **in**
   > > Дюйм (Inch) — соответствует реальному физическому размеру элементов на экране (1 дюйм ≈ 2,54 см)
3. > **mm**
   > > Миллиметр — также соответствует реальному размеру (1 мм = 0,01 см)
4. > **pt**
   > > Точка — 1/72 дюйма, реальный размер (1 точка ≈ 0,35 мм)
5. > **dp** или **dip**
   > > Пиксель, не зависящий от плотности (Density-independent Pixel) — относительная единица измерения, которая берет за основу плотность экрана устройства. Примерно cоответствует одному пискелю на устройстве с плотностью экрана 160 точек на дюйм (dots per inch, dpi). Отношение dp/px меняется в соответствии с плотности экрана, но не в строгой пропорции: dp/dx зависит от категории экрана, а не точного значения плотности. Рекомендуется применять вместо обычных px для корректного отображения элементов на устройствах с различной плотностью экрана. В разметке можно писать как `dip`, так и `dp`, компилятор одинаково воспринимает оба варианта, однако `dp` предпочтительнее.
6. > **sp**
   > > [Scalable Pixel](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskUseDP) или [Scale-independent Pixel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) — как и dp, зависит от плотности экрана, но результат будет масштабироваться в соответствии с настройками размера шрифта пользователя. Рекомендуется для задания размеров шрифтов, чтобы текст подстраивался как под плотность экрана, так и под настройки, заданные пользователем

Из публикации [Understanding Density Independence In Android](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-density-independent-pixel-sp-dp-dip-in-android):

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
| Единица | Название     | В 1 дюйме     | Зависит от | Одинаковый  |
|         |              |               | плотности? | физ. размер |
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  px     | Пиксель      |  —            |  Да        |  Нет        |
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  in     | Дюйм         |  1            |  Нет       |  Да         |
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  mm     | Миллиметр    |  25.4         |  Нет       |  Да         |
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  pt     | Точка        |  72           |  Нет       |  Да         |
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  dp     | Пиксель,     | ~160          |  Нет       |  Нет        |
|         | не зависящий |               |            |             |
|         | от плотности |               |            |             |
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
|  sp     | Пиксель,     | ~160          |  Нет       |  Нет        |
|         | не зависящий |               |            |             |
|         | от масштаби- |               |            |             |
|         | рования      |               |            |             |
+---------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

Наглядно: [Google Design Documentation](https://material.io/design/layout/pixel-density.html).

Comment: ты написал, что "В разметке можно писать как dip, так и dp, компилятор одинаково воспринимает оба варианта, однако dp предпочтительнее."  когда я пишу в CSS-декларации, например, "width:100dp;" или "width:100dip;", то выдает ошибку.

Comment: @Vadik А почему в табличке одинаковый физ. размер у dp стоит нет. Разве это не тоже самое что in, mm и pt только фиксированная величина в данном случае 1/160 дюймов. Я к тому, что как ты не меняй размер экран или его плотность пикселей, физ. размер dp не будет изменяться. Разве нет ?

Comment: Поправлю, что 1pt ≈ 0,35мм, а не 3,5мм